# How do I remove line feeds / line breaks from std::string::String?

Tags: string, split, rust, linefeed

I cannot find something that will do this. What I have so far is only for whitespace:

```
pub fn minify(&self) {
    println!("Minify task started ... ");
    let mut string_iter = self.mystring.split_whitespace();
    for strings in string_iter {
        println!("{}", strings);
    }
}
```

`mystring` is something like:

```
let mystring = "p {
                  text-align: center;
                  color: red;
                } ";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to define what a "line feed" is. I choose the character `\n`. In that case, I'd just use `replace`:

```
println!("{}", string.replace('\n', ""))
```

This works for for `&str` and `String`.

If you didn't need a new string, I'd split on newlines and print them out:

```
pub fn minify(string: &str) {
    for line in string.split('\n') {
        print!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use [`string.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) if you want to treat `\r\n` as the same as `\n`.

Comment: @kennytm a great point! If you make it an answer I'll up vote 

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in-place with either of these two options:

```
string.retain(|c| c != '\n')
```

or (nightly only)

```
string.remove_matches('\n');
```

Check out [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f6781b2ea34fa985866c5eb78417d8e) to see it working